Wordpress is adding "-1" to the filename of media items
On a website I administer, I just noticed that Wordpress is adding "-1" to the filename. Which is expected behavior for a file that has already been uploaded.
But these files have not been previously uploaded and the filenames are unique. Why would this be happening?
In advance, thanks!
